# Remove postgres from Mac that is installed in /usr/local/

Tags: macos, postgresql

I want to completely uninstall postgres and start from scratch - the version I have is refusing to work with PostGIS 2.0. I have read other answers on how to do this, but none of them seem to fit the way postgres is set up on this machine.

I'm not sure postgres was originally installed on this machine - it wasn't via brew or Postgres.app or the EnterpriseDB installer - but it seems to be living in /usr/local:

```
$ which psql
/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql
```

The postgres binary itself is in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`.

How can I kill it forever? Can I simply go to `/usr/local` and do `rm -rf pgsql-9.1`, and the same in `/usr/local/var`, and make sure there are no paths in my profile file?

Sorry if this is a duplicate - I have found other questions that are similar, but none of them says unambiguously exactly what to do once you've found the file location.